# Python 2.7: Replace duplicates in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionries:

```
l = [{u'content': [], u'name': u'child_01'}, {u'content': [], u'name': u'child_01'} ,{u'content': [], u'name': u'child_04'}]
```

and I want detect duplicates and replace them with

```
{u'content': [], u'name': u'child'}
```

`set` did not worked for dictionaries.

Comment: What should the output be for the list in your example?

Comment: Duplicates based on `u'name'` only?

Comment: What about entries with the same key but different value? Both cannot be stored in the same dictionary.

Comment: 1.In output I need replace one of the duplicated dictionary with another one. 2. Yes based on u'name'. 3. I can't change dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not complete answer but maybe it will give you some hint, you can do the following:

```
l = [{u'content': [], u'name': u'child_01'}, {u'content': [], u'name': u'child_01'} ,{u'content': [], u'name': u'child_04'}]

from itertools import groupby
uniques = [key for key, value in groupby(l)]
```

The problem you have is that dictionaries aren't hashable, so you can't invoke `set()`. Now, I know that this solution is not inserting:

```
{u'content': [], u'name': u'child'}
```

for duplicates, but when you'll insert them for each duplicate, you'll create another duplicates, so maybe do it like this. First, reduce your list to have only unique values, and then compare lengths of lists (before and after reduction), and add as many "default" dictionaries as you want, like this:

```
defaults_cnt = len(l) - len(uniques)
default = {u'content': [], u'name': u'child'}
uniques.extend(default for _ in xrange(defaults_cnt))
```

and now:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(uniques)
[{'content': [], 'name': 'child_01'},
 {'content': [], 'name': 'child_04'},
 {'content': [], 'name': 'child'}]
```

Comment: That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class Entry which is a subclass of the `dict` and make it [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-hashable).

```
class Entry(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Entry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['name'] = self['name'].split('_')[0]

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self['name'])

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Entry):
            return self['name'] == other['name']
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other
```

The `name` attribute is normalized in the constructor in order to drop the numeric suffix.

To use this class with `set` you need to define the `__eq__` and `__ne__` operators too.

You can use this class like this to remove duplicates:

```
l = [{u'content': [], u'name': u'child_01'},
     {u'content': [], u'name': u'child_01'},
     {u'content': [], u'name': u'child_04'}]

entries = set(Entry(attrs) for attrs in l)

print(entries)
```

You get a set of one dict:

{{'name': 'child', 'content': []}}